# Sqoop to load data in chunk while doing Historical load

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to figure out a way where I can sqoop data in chunks while doing historical load.

Consider a scenario where i have 3 years of data and when i trigger a sqoop , it will fetch all data in one go and push in HDFS.

I want to avoid putting pressure on cluster , instead of above is there any way to tell sqoop to load data in one month of chunk instead of loading all 3 years of data in one go.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the --query option and filter your table by month and repeat the process 36 days if this is a one time think.

Depending on your Hadoop version, you could try use the --split-by option splitting by year and month (monthly basis), it means that each mapper in your sqoop process will sqoop 1 month and limit the max number of mappers running simultaneously to one

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583

Comment: I do not want one mapper to process 1 month data. My question is around distributing one month of data across mapper to fasten load process during historical load. So Ideally every sqoop call will bring one month of data at a time instead of bringing all 36 (3 years ) months data in single scoop call.

Comment: is not possible run 36 independent sqoops like i suggested using --query? Your scenario is not clear. .. specify what you want to do

Comment: You can use a combination of `-m (or --num-mappers)` with where clause to achieve this. `where` clause will create view of 1month data and then no. of mappers specified will split that data for transfer.